# how can i configure reporting service ssrs in integrated mode?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

i use Microsoft SQL Server2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services , And Sharepoint server 2010 , but i cant congigure this in integrated mode 
show me this error:The feature: "Windows SharePoint Services integration" is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. (rsOperationNotSupported)

what is the suitable edition of sql server to develop reporting service in integrated mode?
give me the link to installation

Comment: I think this might be a question for [serverfault](serverfault.com) rather than SO?

Comment: Actually the [SharePoint StackExchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) might be better

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server 2008 R2 Express [does not support SharePoint integrated mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281020%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you must use standard or enterprise editions.for more information see [this](http://recruitmentexchange.com/download/SQL2008_editions_features.pdf) document.